# Can twilio capability token API in Java accept clientName?

Tags: java, twilio

We need to generate Capability token for our IOS twilio Client. The capability token is generated on the server side which is in Java.
The sample code available in twilio website,which is in PHP has an API as follows-

```
$capability->allowClientOutgoing($appSid, array(), $clientName);
```

If we use Java sdk or libraries, the API available is either -

```
capability.allowClientOutgoing(applnsid)
```

OR

```
capability.allowClientOutgoing(appSid, params)
```

The difference here is the "clientName" being passed in PHP code 
In java the API doesn't accept a third parameter.

So In Java is there any way by which we can assign clientName for generating capability token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Sure, you can absolutely generate a capability token in Java.  Check out this Gist that shows how to generate a token using the Java helper library:

https://gist.github.com/Beans0063/1201918

In the Gist you can see that there are two methods, one called allowClientOutgoing which takes an appSid, and another called allowClientIncoming which takes a client name as a string.

Hope that helps.